# Fixed bars with vertical text

Tags: css, css-position, css-transforms

So, I have got this interesting problem that I can't figure out.

I'm trying to make a menu of vertical bars, all 100% height of the window. They have a fixed position. I want the text to be vertical. Please check the sketch I've made:

[image]

And this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aYTWG/).

The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<header>
    header
</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">bar 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bar 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bar 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">bar 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgb(42,42,42);
    background: rgba(10,10,10,0.95);
}
nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 75px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    background: blue;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    background: #f3b200;
}
nav ul li:nth-child(1) a { background: #c61c05; }
nav ul li:nth-child(2) a { background: #dc572e; }
nav ul li:nth-child(3) a { background: #d27b26; }
nav ul li:nth-child(4) a { background: #f3b200; }
```

Now the problem is that I can't figure out how to position the `nav` like I want. Every measurement I give (width, height, top position, left position) is given to it based on a 0 degree rotation. The rotation is made after that.

So the height isn't 100% of the viewport's height, but 100% viewport width.

I also tried turning the `ul` inside the `nav`, and the `li` inside it, but can't figure out the right way to position this `nav` bar.

I'm looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: What if you tried something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aYTWG/3/. That only rotates the text within the link, and instead targets the height of the parent, rather than the width.

Comment: @oGeez, thank you. After adding `direction: rtl` and `white-space: no-wrap` to the `span` I got it working perfectly. Please add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm right in thinking you want everything 100% the height of the page, use the flow of the page rather than changing `position`. Float your navigation next to your header and so forth. You can then rotate some `<span>`s inside your links instead of the entire thing. Here is an alteration. I'll leave the rest up to you:

**HTML**

```
<header>header</header>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>bar 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>bar 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>bar 3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>bar 4</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="other">Loads of other content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
header {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width: 250px;
    background: rgb(42, 42, 42);
    background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.95);
}
ul{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
ul li{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}

ul li a{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
}

ul li a span{
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    font-size:26px;
    width:60px;
    direction: rtl;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/aYTWG/6/)

Answer (score 0):

How does this look?

`html`:

```
<div class="mainWrap">
    <header class="mainBody">

    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="sBar s-1"><span class="rot">Bar 1</span></li>
            <li class="sBar s-2"><span class="rot">Bar 2</span></li>
            <li class="sBar s-3"><span class="rot">Bar 3</span></li>
            <li class="sBar s-4"><span class="rot">Bar 4</span></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

`css`:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    border: 4px solid red;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.mainWrap, .mainWrap nav, .mainWrap ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.mainWrap li, .mainWrap header {
    float: left;
}

.mainBody {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2b2b2b;
}

.sBar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    display: block;
}

.s-1 {
    background: #c61c05;
}

.s-2 {
    background: #dc572e;
}

.s-3 {
    background: #d27b26;
}

.s-4 {
    background: #f3b200;
}

.rot {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle: [Remove "show" in url to view and alter code](http://jsfiddle.net/TrKH9/1/show/)